# How to make when logged in the wrapper class in Concrete5 acted like a frame for a template

Tags: concrete5

I recently designed a one-page website for myself using the latest Concrete5. My site uses a dynamic sticky nav which later turns into a fixed nav to the top when I scroll down. The tool bar covers the fixed nav and I cannot see it again until I scroll back to the top.

What I am interested in is this. Is there a way to have the wrapper class that C5 needs for editing to behave like an iFrame from days gone by. The effect that I am looking for is that everything under the toolbar be the website and still be editable.

Answer (score 1):

When the concrete5 toolbar is visible, the `html` element in your HTML will have the `ccm-toolbar-visible` class.

With this class, you can change your navigation behavior based on the toolbar visibility. A common approach is to set the navigation position from `fixed` to `static` when the toolbar is visible.

Additional information on this topic can be found here:

- https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/theme-fixed-header-in-admin-mode/#860110
- https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/trying-to-make-a-header-stationary/#762608